# mystery axis 0 and 1 direction

Tags: python, numpy

Upon following the 'Python for data analysis' on Chapter numpy, encounter such an example

```
#+BEGIN_SRC ipython :session my :export both :results output
arr = np.random.randn(5, 4)
print(arr)
#+END_SRC
#+RESULTS:
: [[-1.20142965 -0.65152972  2.04732169 -2.27351496]
:  [ 1.0054648  -1.75728785  0.00923428 -0.65533187]
:  [-2.1108598  -0.92347845  0.46443361 -0.48219059]
:  [ 0.77617699  0.40242098  1.09411003 -0.6431827 ]
:  [-0.59485821  1.22890193 -0.7498006   0.93518233]]
```

It states that

> Functions like mean and sum take an optional axis argument that computes the statistic over the given axis, resulting in an array with one fewer dimension:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC ipython :session my :export both :results output
print(arr.mean(axis=1))
print(arr.sum(axis=0))
#+END_SRC
#+RESULTS:
: [-0.51978816 -0.34948016 -0.76302381  0.40738132  0.20485636]
: [-2.12550586 -1.70097313  2.86529902 -3.11903779]
```

Then the book explains that

> Here, arr.mean(1) means “compute mean across the columns” where arr.sum(0) means “compute sum down the rows.”

I assume Mr.McKinnney did a perfect job to explain in an opposite way.

arr.sum(0) means to compute a row which across the columns
arr.mean(1) means to mean down the rows in a  column or vertical direction.

Any problem with my understanding?

Comment: I think the word "across" is just too ambiguous to be clear as it could arguably be understood in both ways.

Comment: When working with 2d arrays, these explanations of the `axis` can be confusing.  It's  easier to picture what's happening in a 1d array with `axis=0`, or a 3d array, where you reduce just one of the 3 axes.  Sometimes it helps to add the `keepdims=True` parameter.

Comment: 1d array is with axis =0  or axis =1? should view as array vertically or horozontally as default? @hpaulj

Comment: A 1d array has only one axis.  Mean or sum on that axis reduces the array to a scalar (which can be thought of as a 0d array).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do along some axis means reduce over dimension along it.
so :

```
import numpy as np



arr = np.array([[1,2,3] , 
                [4,5,6]])


print(arr.sum(axis = 0))

print(arr.sum(axis = 1))
```

First one reduces along axis= 0  what is outer one or 'vertically' as you d say and returns [1+4, 2+5, 3+6]

Second one recudes along each row [1+2+3, 4+5+6]

Comment: ok lol it depends how to  view on matrix,  rows are usualy horizontally 
horizontally is : : "arr.sum(0) means to compute a row which across the columns in vertical direction
arr.mean(1) means along the row in horizontal direction".

Comment: view a matrix as it display, I think the answer prove it wrong.

Comment: yes this from book is *wrong*, but sometimes in literature especially old you can see rows and columns swapped